# ¿Por qué no se muestra el texto en los botones ubicados con place dentro de un ciclo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Llevo poco tiempo en esto de programar y haciendo alguna pruebas me he topado con este problema, cuando ejecuto el código , solo me muestra el texto en los últimos botones, los de las 2 primeras filas que están en un bucle no los muestra y no lo entiendo.

Este es mi código:

```
from tkinter import Tk , Button , Frame

vp=Tk()
frame_botones=Frame(vp)
z=1
for i in range(7):
    fz=Frame(frame_botones)
    if i==0:
        for j in range(4):
            bt=Button(fz,text=str(z)).place(relx=j*0.25,relwidth=1, relheight=1)
            z+=1
        fz.place(relwidth=1,relheight=0.04)
    elif i==1:
        for j in range(4):
            bt=Button(fz,text=str(z)).place(relx=j*0.25,relwidth=1, relheight=1)
            z+=1
        fz.place(rely=0.04,relwidth=1, relheight=0.11)
    else:
        bt=Button(fz,text=str(z)).place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        fz.place(rely=0.15+((i-2)*0.17),relwidth=1, relheight=0.17)
        z+=1
frame_botones.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
vp.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en que el ancho de cada botón es el mismo que el del frame que contiene a los cuatro, dado que usas `relwidth=1` en `place`. Esto hace que los botones se solapen, no es que el texto no se muestre, es que queda oculto por el siguiente botón o fuera de la ventana en el caso del último. Con un ejemplo simplificado con texto mas largo y modificando la altura relativa de cada botón es más simple ver que está pasando:

```
from tkinter import Tk , Button , Frame

vp = Tk()
frame = Frame(vp)
frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

colores = ("red", "green", "blue", "orange")
for i in range(1, 5):
    btn = Button(frame, text="Hola Stackoverflow en español", background=colores[i-1])
    btn.place(relx=(i-1)*0.2, relwidth=1, relheight=1/i)
    
vp.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Simplemente asigna un cuarto del ancho del frame para cada botón como haces con la posición mediante `relwidth=0.25`:

```
from tkinter import Tk , Button , Frame

vp = Tk()
frame_botones = Frame(vp)
z = 1

for i in range(7):
    fz = Frame(frame_botones)
    if i == 0:
        for j in range(4):
            b = Button(fz, text=str(z))
            b.place(relx=j*0.25, relwidth=0.25, relheight=1)
            z += 1
            print(z)
        fz.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.04)
   
    elif i == 1:
        for j in range(4):
            b = Button(fz, text=str(z))
            b.place(relx=j*0.25, relwidth=0.25, relheight=1)
            z += 1
        fz.place(rely=0.04, relwidth=1, relheight=0.11)
    
    else:
        Button(fz, text=str(z)).place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        fz.place(rely=0.15+((i-2)*0.17), relwidth=1, relheight=0.17)
        z += 1
        
frame_botones.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
vp.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`place` es mucho más flexible que `pack` o `grid` pero hay que tener en cuenta que simplemente habilita a especificar el tamaño y posición del widget de forma explícita (tanto absoluta como relativamente). Esto implica que los widgets se pueden solapar (flotantes) o incluso rebasar el tamaño del widget padre (en cuyo caso solo se mostrará la parte que quede dentro). Por ello, hay que ser cuidadoso a la hora de especificar la posición, el tamaño y la relación entre ellas de cada widget hijo con su padre.

Comment: madre mia, claro, soy medio tonto, como no me di cuenta de ello, gracias por tu ayuda, si he probado los otros metodos, pero para trabajar con fullscreen me parece que este es el mas estetico, gracias de nuevo